# Draw rounded rectangle using RectF and canvas?

Tags: android

I'm attempting to draw a rounded rectangle using RectF and canvas.drawRoundRect(). Please see my code below:

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create main RL params
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlMainlayoutParams 
                = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        // Create main relative layout
        RelativeLayout rlMain = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rlMain.setLayoutParams(rlMainlayoutParams);
        //rlMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgndlogin);
        rlMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        RectF rectf = new RectF(200, 400, 200, 400);
        CustomRectangle customRectangle = new CustomRectangle(this, rectf, 5, 5, "#FFFF00");

        //
        rlMain.addView(customRectangle);

        setContentView(rlMain);
    }

    //!< Draw the log in rectangle shaped panel
    public class CustomRectangle extends View {
        Paint paint;
        float left_side, top_side;
        String color;
        RectF rectf;

        //!< Constructor for the log in rectangle shaped panel
        public CustomRectangle(Context context, RectF rectf, float left_side, float top_side, String color) {
            super(context);

            this.rectf = rectf;
            this.left_side= left_side;
            this.top_side = top_side;
            this.color = color;

        }

        //!< Implement to draw the rectangle
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            //paint.setAlpha(61);

            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectf, left_side, top_side, paint);

        }
    }

}
```

The program runs but nothing gets drawn i.e. I just get my white background screen. Any ideas as to why?

Note: I'm creating my relative layout programatically as opposed to using XML for scaling purposes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually here your `RectF` representing `Point` not `Rectangle`, that's why you are unable to see `Rect`...

```
RectF rectF = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
```

and here `RectF` is

```
RectF rectf = new RectF(200, 400, 200, 400); // representing Point
```

here `left = right = 200` and `top = bottom = 400` which represents a `Point`

if you want to draw a `Rect` of `width = 200` and `height = 400`, then your `RectF` should be

```
RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 400);
```

and for `width = 400 and height = 200`, `RectF` should be

```
RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 400, 200);
```

Answer (score 2):

As in [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html)

> RectF holds four float coordinates for a rectangle. The rectangle is represented by the coordinates of its 4 edges (left, top, right bottom).

```
RectF rectf = new RectF(left, top, right, bottom);
```

In the snippet, the RectF Arguments as the docs say represents the edges coordinates of the Rectangle.

As a conclusion,
 width = | left - right |
 height = | top - bottom |

If the width and height were 0 as in the question it would not represent a view nor an object,
which in logic is impossible for an object to exist of the height, width and depth of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You have not created proper rectangle. Give your rectangle proper left ,top, right, bottom points like: `RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 480, 854);`

Answer (score 1):

Cheers guys. Spot on. I've corrected my code as seen below and now I can see my rectangle.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.graphics.RectF;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create main RL params
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlMainlayoutParams 
                = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        // Create main relative layout
        RelativeLayout rlMain = new RelativeLayout(this);
        rlMain.setLayoutParams(rlMainlayoutParams);
        //rlMain.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgndlogin);
        rlMain.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 300);
        CustomRectangle customRectangle = new CustomRectangle(this, rectf, 15, 15, "#FFFF00");

        //
        rlMain.addView(customRectangle);

        setContentView(rlMain);
    }

    //!< Draw the log in rectangle shaped panel
    public class CustomRectangle extends View {
        Paint paint;
        float left_side, top_side;
        String color;
        RectF rectf;

        //!< Constructor for the log in rectangle shaped panel
        public CustomRectangle(Context context, RectF rectf, float left_side, float top_side, String color) {
            super(context);

            this.rectf = rectf;
            this.left_side= left_side;
            this.top_side = top_side;
            this.color = color;

        }

        //!< Implement to draw the rectangle
        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(color));
            paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
            //paint.setAlpha(61);

            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectf, left_side, top_side, paint);

        }
    }

}
```